# Error NoReverseMatch en Django cuando hago render

Tags: django

Cada vez que hago click al elemento en el Html me sale este mensaje, parece que me falta un elemento pero no entiendo si es en el Urls (slug) o en el contexto del render (return render(request, 'post.html', contexto)) que falta algún argumento.
No he encontrado muchas referencias a mi problema.
Este mensaje me sale:

```
NoReverseMatch at /mejores-laptops-10/
Reverse for 'detalle_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/mejores-laptops-10/
Django Version: 3.1.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'detalle_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Error during template rendering
In template C:\ARTURO\Proyectos_Laptop\Pagina_Web_blog\CavernicolaInformatico\templates\index.html, error at line 0

Reverse for 'detalle_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
1   {% load static %}
2   <!DOCTYPE html>
3   <html lang="en">
4    <head>
5      <title>{% block titulo %}CAVERNICOLA INFORMATICO{% endblock titulo %}</title>
6      <meta charset="utf-8">
7      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
8   
9      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700|Playfair+Display:400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
10
```

Y me señala esta parte:

```
C:\ARTURO\Proyectos_Laptop\Pagina_Web_blog\CavernicolaInformatico\aplicaciones\base\views.py, line 49, in get
    return render(request, 'post.html', contexto)
```

Este es mi View:

```
class DetallePost(DetailView):
    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        print("hasta aqui")
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(slug = slug)
            print("hasta aqui 2")
        except :
            post = 'None'
        print(post)
        contexto = {
            'post': post,
        
        }
        print("hasta aqui")
        return render(request, 'post.html', contexto)
```

Este es mi model:

```
class  Post(ModeloBase):
titulo = models.CharField('Título del Post',max_length = 150, unique = True)
slug = models.CharField('Slug', max_length = 150, unique = True)
descripcion = models.TextField('Descripción')
autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
contenido = RichTextField()
imagen_referencial = models.ImageField('Imagen Referencial', upload_to = 'imagenes/', max_length = 255)
publicado = models.BooleanField('Publicado / No Publicado',default = False)
fecha_publicacion = models.DateField('Fecha de Publicación')

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Post'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Posts'

def __str__(self):
    return self.titulo
```

Este es mi url:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Inicio, DetallePost
urlpatterns = [
path('', Inicio.as_view(), name = 'index'),
path('<slug:slug>/', DetallePost.as_view(), name = 'detalle_post'),
]
```

Este es la línea que corresponde a mi Index.html

```
<h2 class="mb-4"><a href="{% url 'base:detalle_post' principal.slug %}">{{principal.titulo 
| upper}}</a></h2>
```

Cualquier sugerencia les estaré agradecido, no soy muy bueno en Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto.

Al momento de pasarle los argumentos para renderizar la página html, el problema estaba en el View.py, faltaba agregar más elementos

Answer (score 0):

Error de indentación para el método `get` de la clase `DetallePost` ?

```
class DetallePost(DetailView):
def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    print("hasta aqui")
```

Comment: Fue un error mío al postearlo, ya lo corregí @DanielCast